# Bigcommerce menu item to redirect to registration/log in page

Tags: bigcommerce

I want to be able to have my menu item "wholesale" redirected to registration/log in page that I currently have set up. From there after the user/customer signs in if they are registered already I want them to be sent to the original "wholesale" page.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Bigcommerce gives us the variable "%%GLOBAL_CurrentCustomerFirstName%%", will evaluate to empty (""), or "Guest" if the user is not logged in.

Knowing this, I have created this script to handle manipulating account page list items whether the user is logged in or not.

```
    <li class="wholesale">
         <script type="text/javascript">
               var GlobalFname="%%GLOBAL_CurrentCustomerFirstName%%";

               if (GlobalFname !="" && GlobalFname!="Guest"){
                   $('li.wholesale').html('<a href="/your-login-page-here/">Wholesale</a>');
               } else {
                   $('li.wholesale').html('<a href="/actual-wholesale-area/">Wholesale</a>');

              };
         </script>
    </li>
```

As you can see, the user will always see the "Wholsale" li in the list, but there will be different links behind the item depending on if they are logged in or not.

I often use this for the Login/Logout text as the Bigcommerce variable meant for this is not always available/reliable.

Hope this helps.